# Assert Fails Even java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I get this error when i run it. I'm trying to run it and I changed return true and return false later. Do you know why it happens?

```
public static boolean elementIsPresent(MobileElement element) {
    try {
        element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void checkbox() {
    try {
        Assert.assertTrue(elementIsPresent(this.CimonCheckBox));
        Log.log(driver).info("Passes matches Cimon Name");
        Assert.assertTrue(elementIsPresent(this.KurwaCheckbox));
        Log.log(driver).info("Passes matches names");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail("CheckBox: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Here are  the web elements:  @AndroidFindBy(xpath = cimonbox)
   private MobileElement CimonCheckBox;
   
   @AndroidFindBy(xpath = kurwabox)
   private MobileElement KurwaCheckbox;

Comment: You should edit the original question instead of adding more information as a comment.

Comment: `KurwaCheckbox` :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your if statement is backwards. You're returning true if you get a NoSuchElementException and false otherwise. If you want to consider "is displayed" as "present" then I think your method should be:

```
public static boolean elementIsPresent(MobileElement element) {
    try {
        return element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

or if you simply want to return true if it's present (regardless of whether it is displayed or not) then it can be:

```
 public static boolean elementIsPresent(MobileElement element) {
        try {
            element.isDisplayed();
        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Could you put those two method in one method through for loop? Make it shorter.